# Binding view with object properties in angular 2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am fetching user data from firebase database, and binding class object with that data. Data fetching is working fine, But when I try to bind it with class object in typescript file, it is showing warning "No implementation found for object", but I have already declare object.

Below is my code,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFireAuth, AngularFireAuthProvider } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserInfo } from "./models/userInfo";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  currentUser : Observable<UserInfo>;

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public router: Router) {
    this.user = afAuth.authState;

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        let fireBaseUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        if(fireBaseUser)
        {
          console.log("fire - ", fireBaseUser.uid);
          this.currentUser = firebase.database().ref('/users/' + fireBaseUser.uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
              console.log(snapshot.val());
              return snapshot.val();
            });

        }
      } else {
        router.navigateByUrl('/login');
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Below is my view,

```
user.uid - <div> {{ (user | async)?.uid }} </div> // display correct value
<div> cc - {{ currentUser }} </div> // empty.
```

Below is error,

[image: Error info]

I guess, the problem is, I am trying to fill currentUser object in Observable scope. So it is not able to found my initialized object. What do I need to change to make it work.

Comment: you are trying to assign Promise to observable, currentUser is observable and firebase.database()... is Promise

Comment: is 'this' in the same context inside onAuthStateChanged? You might need something like... 1)  _that = this above firebaseAuth - and 2) _that .currentUser instead of this.currentUser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)